# value of type integer cannot be converted to 1-dimensional array of integer

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Im looking at a VB project. It defines a Integer array:

```
Dim BatchIDs As Integer()
```

Then it tries to populate this array using a method

```
BatchIDs = m_oBatMan.GetBatchIDs(BatchClassName)
```

The method does return an array

```
Public ReadOnly Property GetBatchIDs() As Integer()
```

But the line populating BatchIDs is giving me the error: value of type integer cannot be converted to 1-dimensional array of integer.

Im not a VB programmer but Im assigning an array using a method that returns an array. I dont see the problem. If I change it so BatchIDs is just an Integer and not an array then its okay. But GetBatchIDs returns an array so I dont understand what is going on. Anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the property returns an array but has no parameter. You think that you are using it with an argument but actually you are accessing one index of the array (if `BatchClassName` is an `Integer`).

So write it in this way:

```
BatchIDs = m_oBatMan.GetBatchIDs
```

But it seems not to be the real/complete code since it does not even compile.

```
Public ReadOnly Property GetBatchIDs() As Integer()
```

gives an: [*"'ReadOnly' property must provide a 'Get'"*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2ak62h1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

But if you add the getter:

```
m_oBatMan.GetBatchIDs(BatchClassName)
```

returns an `Integer` not an `Integer`-array because you are using the indexer ( which is `()` in VB.NET as opposed to C# where it is `[]` ). Of course presuming that `BatchClassName` is an Integer which you still haven't mentioned.

Comment: When I right click it and choose go to definition it goes to that method though. Its weird. I think something in the project is screwed up

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the project. Notice that `GetBatchIDs()` is not a method; is a property, of type "Array of Integers". When you use it like Tim said, you are accessing the whole array; when you use like your example, you are accessing only one element of the array.

Comment: Can you show the real code since your code does not even compile. `Public ReadOnly Property GetBatchIDs() As Integer()` gives an: [_"'ReadOnly' property must provide a 'Get'"_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2ak62h1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) But if you add the getter `m_oBatMan.GetBatchIDs(BatchClassName)` returns an `Integer` not an integer-array because you are using the indexer (which is `(]` in VB.NET as opposed to C# where it is `[]` ). Of course presuming that `BatchClassName` is an `Integer` which you haven't mentioned.

Comment: ... there was a typo in my comment, `(]` was meant to be `()`.